# python-pptx: read background colour from slide layout

Tags: python-pptx

I want to read all the different ways slide background colours can be set. So far, I have learnt that you can set the background colour at:

1. slide master level
2. slide layout level
3. slide level

I am able to successfully extract the background colour from 1st and the 3rd approach, but I can't seem to read background colour which is set at slide layout level.

```
for idx, slide in enumerate(prs.slides):
    is_inherited = slide.follow_master_background
    print "slide background is inherited: ", is_inherited
    if is_inherited:
        print "    slide ", idx, "background color: ", slide.slide_layout.slide_master.background.fill.fore_color.rgb
    else:
        print "    slide ", idx, "background color: ", slide.background.fill.fore_color.rgb
print "\n"
```

I would have imaged that this would have worked but it returns an error:

```
slide.slide_layout.background.fill.fore_color.rgb
```

error:

```
TypeError: fill type _NoFill has no foreground color, call .solid() or .patterned() first
```

Screenshot below shows the 2nd slide is using a slide background colour from the slide layout and the slide layout is not using the same background colour as the slide master.

[image]

Comment: Working on something similar. Could you please share how did you access the color through the other 2 methods (master and slide level)?